# How to display a text string as label when a button is clicked in PyQt4 (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am a novice in creating app using PyQt. My question may be silly but please bear with me.
I have written a code to display a text string as a label when the button is clicked. I am not getting the output. Please tell me what is the error and how do i rectify it ??

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100,100,600,600)
        self.setWindowTitle("healapp")
        self.pbtn()


    def pbtn(self):

        btn1=QtGui.QPushButton('hi',self)
        btn1.move(100,100)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttnpress)


    def buttnpress(self):
        labl=QtGui.QLabel(self)
        labl.setText("clicked")



def main():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI=Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move label initialization `labl=QtGui.QLabel(self)` into `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Window,self).__init__()
    self.setGeometry(100,100,600,600)
    self.setWindowTitle("healapp")
    self.pbtn()
    self.labl=QtGui.QLabel(self)
```

then modify `buttnpress()` accordingly:

```
def buttnpress(self):
    # you can move it if you like
    self.labl.move(100,200)
    self.labl.setText("clicked")
```

Comment: Thanks!!can you please tell me hoe to change the font size

Comment: @pavansunder sure, it's easy: 
`MyFont = QtGui.QFont()
MyFont.setPointSize(20)
self.labl.setFont(MyFont)`